# sql oracle connect two sql's outputs

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have problems connecting two SQL's to get at the end one output not two.
**Both SQL's are working fine solo**!

My SQL's are the following:

SQL 1:

```
select
table2.displayvalue,
(count(table2.displayvalue)*5)
from
table1,
table2
where
table1.abteilung = table2.STOREDVALUE
and table1.AKTIV = 1
group by table2.displayvalue
```

SQL's 1 output:

```
column#1_1   column#2_1

Blue        15
Red          5
Yellow      15
Pink       120
Black       75
LessBlack   20
MoreBlack  140
Green       10
DarkRed     10
FireRed    135 
FireGreen   25
LessGreen    5
```

SQL 2:

```
    SELECT Projektabteilung,
       SUM(DATUM) TAGEIST
FROM(
        select 
        table2.DISPLAYVALUE Projektabteilung,
        table1.IDENTNAME,
        count(DISTINCT trunc(table4.datum)) DATUM 
        from
        table2,
        table1,
        table3,
        table4
        where
        table1.ABTEILUNG = table2.STOREDVALUE
        and table1.PROJEKTBENUTZERID = table3.PROJEKTBENUTZERFK
        and table3.PROJEKTMITARBEITERID = table4.PROJEKTMITARBEITERFK
        AND table4.datum BETWEEN sysdate-7 and sysdate
        AND TO_CHAR(table4.datum, 'D') NOT IN ('6', '7')
        group by table2.DISPLAYVALUE,table1.IDENTNAME)
GROUP BY Projektabteilung
```

SQL's 2 output:

```
column#1_2       column#2_2

Pink           35
Black           9
LessBlack       7
Moreblack      17
FireRed        30
FireGreen       2
```

At the end, running the SQL, I would like to have the following output:

```
column#1_1 & column#2_1 together | column#1_2 | column#2_2

Blue                              15               0              
Red                                5               0
Yellow                            15               0
Pink                             120              35
Black                             75               9
LessBlack                         20               7
MoreBlack                        140              17
Green                             10               0
DarkRed                           10               0
FireRed                          135              30 
FireGreen                         25               2
LessGreen                          5               0
```

I tried everything but its killing me. Do you have any help for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Without providing sample data, table, expected output its like you want to see things in the crystal ball...;)

Comment: I edited my post - hope its clear now

Comment: Nope. It is not clear. Try to provide SQL fiddle or table definition and query. This certainly can be done, but to help You we need details.

Comment: By what logic are the two row sets connected, so that 1 and 3 are joined together, 2 and 5, etc.

Comment: What result do you expect if a row is added to one of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neither posted your table structure nor your queries, so this is very hard to answer.

If you can add some kind of column that "maps" a row from the first query to the rows of the second query, you could do something like this.

```
with headline_1 (headline, rn) as (
  select ..., --<<< your original columns go here
         row_number() over (order by something) as rn
  from ...
), headline_2 (headline, rn) as (
  select ..., --<<< your original columns go here
         row_number() over (order by something) as rn
  from ...
)select h1.headline, h2.headline
from headline_1 h1
  full outer join headline_2 h2 on h1.rn = h2.rn
order by h1.rn;
```

The `row_number() over (order by something) as rn` generates a unique number for each row in the result and the rows from the two queries are matched by that number. You should find a column to order by that gives you a stable sort.

**Edit after the question was enhanced**

It seems you want to do an outer join on the first column:

```
with query_1 (column#1_1, column#2_1) as (
  .. your original first query goes here ...
), 
query_2 (column#1_2, column#2_2) as (
  .. your original second query goes here ...
)
select coalesce(q1.column#1_1, q2.column#1_2) as col1, 
       coalesce(q1.column#2_1, 0) as col2_1, 
       coalesce(q2.column#2_2, 0) as col2_2
from query_1 q1 
  full outer join query_2 q2 on q1.column#1_1 = q2.column#1_2
order by 1
```

Comment: @piguy: sounds as if you just want to do a full outer join on the first column than. No need to generate a row index.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post as well - my problem now is I dont really now how to include your suggestion to my code?

Comment: ah I just say your comments

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO to connect you could just execute the two queries and use nextRowSet() to advance to the second query.

in php I use this to get an insert id for example in the second query.

```
$q = $db->prepare($query . $queryfieldnames .')'. $queryvalues.');SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id');
    foreach($myarr as $key => $value) {
        $q->bindParam(':'.$key,$myarr[$key]);
    }
    $q->execute();
    $q->nextRowSet();
    $res = $q->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    $insertid = $res['id'];
```

Comment: There is no `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in Oracle

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but I was giving it as an example of how I use next row set. Not saying I use oracle. NextRowSet is a feature of the pdo driver. He can replace the select scope identity with any arbitrary query he wants. OP did not provide enough detail of what he's doing and what he's doing it in. so i'm giving a generic answer.